# Why am I getting error 1264: Out of range value for column 'ping' at row 1?

Tags: mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector-python

size of the ping is 10,

table data is {'ping': 48.68, 'download': 0.41, 'upload': 0.12}

then how come float value of size 5 throwing error:

> mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1264: Out of range value for column 'ping' at row 1

Here is my mysql table

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| ping           | float(10,10) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| download       | float(10,10) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| upload         | float(10,10) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| datetime_added | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type:

> [Floating-Point Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html)
>
> MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax: FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE PRECISION(M,D). **Here, (M,D) means than values can be stored with up to M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point.**

So:  `float(10,10)`  does not allow for storing 48.68. Before decimal point could be only `0`.

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=569539959e8a7358b746f8a7ff91e1d7)**